# Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::bindParam()

Tags: php, cakephp, stored-procedures

I getting trouble to solve this issue, i get

> Call to undefined method
>   Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::bindParam()

that error in to save data in database using procedure calling.

this is my post method code ...

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$pi_classroom_name = $this->request->getData('classroom_name');
$pi_grade = $this->request->getData('grade');
$pi_subject = $this->request->getData('subject');
$pi_user_id = 1;
$sql = 'CALL jh_add_update_classroom(:pi_classroom_id,:pi_classroom_name,:pi_grade,:pi_subject,:pi_user_id,@po_classroom_id,@po_status,@po_status_message)';
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':pi_classroom_id', null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pi_classroom_name', $pi_classroon_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pi_grade', $pi_grade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pi_subject', $pi_subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':pi_user_id', $pi_user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, there is no such method. You're not operating on a native `\PDOStatement` object, but on a `\Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement` object (which extends a `\Cake\Database\StatementInterface` implementation), the correct method to use for binding is `bind()` or `bindValue()`.

```
$stmt->bindValue('pi_classroom_id', null, 'string');
$stmt->bindValue('pi_classroom_name', $pi_classroom_name, 'string');
// ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Binding Values](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#binding-values)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\StatementInterface::bind()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_bind)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\StatementInterface::bindValue()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_bindValue)**

Comment: Thanks ndm,  but i still getting this warning "Undefined variable: pi_classroon_name"? why? if you get chance to please reply.

Comment: Compare that with the variable that you've declared, it says "roo**m**", the one that you're passing says "roo**n**". I've updated my example.